# LibreOffice file conversion not working in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, libreoffice

while try to convert doc to pdf in node Js Receiving this below error:
Error converting file: Error: Command failed: "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" -env:UserInstallation=file://C:\Users\gokul\AppData\Local\Temp\soffice-9408-gwWbedbmnEKn --headless --convert-to .pdf --outdir C:\Users\gokul\AppData\Local\Temp\libreofficeConvert_-9408-pz1GShMMuHfF C:\Users\gokul\AppData\Local\Temp\libreofficeConvert_-9408-pz1GShMMuHfF\source

Comment: I'd suggest adding more detail about what commands you were running, the environment in which you were running it, and any additional output if you have any.